# Load thumbnail of video from live server

Tags: android, video, streaming, thumbnails

I need to load thumbnail image of video from server. I have only a path to that video which is at server. is it somehow i manage to load the video thumbnail to imageview. What i've tried so far is.

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( trailerLink, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        ImgBanner.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

it returns me null otherwise i able to set the bitmap image.

Comment: are using any third party server ?eg youtube

Comment: Check out ,they will be having the link to the thumbnail of the video..

Answer (score 0):

I dont think u can generate the thumbnail of the video by just giving the video link to the ThumbnailManager,

**2 approaches which i can suggest is**

1. The server which is storing the video should store the thumbnail of
   the video as well so that u can directly download the thumbnail
   image
2. download video and get thumbnail out of that.This approach is not right anyways.

If you are using some third party server eg. youtube or something then they will be having the separate link for thumbnail of video.

Comment: thanks. this is what i already know. is there something what exactly i need?

Comment: Which third party server you are using? Check with the server once ... I think that is the only way